# AVD automatically closed in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio 2.3.1; when I launch the virtual device the emulator is automatically closed.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Creating AVD with the Software (GLS) graphics option worked for me. It has to do with your graphics card.
Open AVD Manager Manager, select your AVD, select "Edit this AVD". In the new window (Virtual Device Configuration) find Emulated Performance, Graphics. Select the "Software (GLS)" option.